# How to get table data after parsing HTML from a url in iOS Swift 3

Tags: html, ios, swift

I am developing an iOS app in which I need to parse html from a link with kanna api. I have done it. But it's shown all of the html file. I need to show just a portion of data like this

```
    <table width="880" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="81"><strong>Trip Name </strong></td>
    <td width="159"><div align="center"><strong>Starting Time from Campus </strong></div></td>
    <td width="186"><div align="center"><strong>Starting Spot &amp; Time </strong></div></td>
    <td width="444"><strong>Remarks</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">Normal-1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">6:30 AM </div></td>
    <td>Rupsha, 7:20 AM </td>
    <td>Will back via Royalmore &amp; Ferighat  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">Normal-1</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">6:45 AM </div></td>
    <td>Moylapota, 7:25 AM </td>
    <td>Will back via Shibbari - Sonadangha </td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

I have used this portion of code in swift 3 to show all html data.

```
let html = "<html>...</html>"

if let doc = HTML(html: html, encoding: .utf8) {
    // Search for nodes by XPath
    for link in doc.xpath("//a | //link") {
        print(link["href"])
    }
}
```

Now I want to get only the table portion of html data. How can I do it?

Comment: The website you get the HTML does not offer an API I suppose.? If the website is yours; you are on a bad way mate. You have to develop an API and use it to get the data. You shouldn't get the HTML and parse it.

Comment: The HTML doesn't offer JSON file. I want to parse some data in my app mate

Comment: Then you should ask for an API from the website owners. That's what they should (must) offer. But if you can't ask for it, let me know, then I will create a project and try to solve your problem. I didn't parse an HTML for 4 years.

Comment: You should definitely be looking for an API. Almost all modern sites do, or if they don't, it's either because they're too small, or they don't want people stealing their content. If you must scrape the site, at least use something like https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup.

Comment: The website owner's didn't give me the api. So I've to do it by web sraping. Would we try for me mate @ArdaOğulÜçpınar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
    //I replaced " with ' to make it easier. But it shouldn't be a problem in your case.
    let html = "<table width='880' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>"
    + "<tr>"
    + "<td width='81'><strong>Trip Name </strong></td>"
    + "<td width='159'><div align='center'><strong>Starting Time from Campus </strong></div></td>"
    + "<td width='186'><div align='center'><strong>Starting Spot &amp; Time </strong></div></td>"
    + "<td width='444'><strong>Remarks</strong></td>"
    + "</tr>"
    + "<tr>"
    + "<td><div align='center'>Normal-1</div></td>"
    + "<td><div align='center'>6:30 AM </div></td>"
    + "<td>Rupsha, 7:20 AM </td>"
    + "<td>Will back via Royalmore &amp; Ferighat  </td>"
    + "</tr>"
    + "<tr>"
    + "<td><div align='center'>Normal-1</div></td>"
    + "<td><div align='center'>6:45 AM </div></td>"
    + "<td>Moylapota, 7:25 AM </td>"
    + "<td>Will back via Shibbari - Sonadangha </td>"
    + "</tr>"
    + "</table>"


    var infoFromHTML : [[String]] = []

    if let doc = try? HTML(html: html, encoding: .utf8) {
        var row : [String] = []
        //look for td tags, not a or link tags
        for (index, td) in doc.css("td").enumerated(){

            row.append(td.text as! String)

            if index%4 == 3{
                //if all row text are added to the row array, append it to info, and reset
                infoFromHTML.append(row)
                row = []
            }
        }
    }
    print(infoFromHTML)
```

Here is your output:

```
    [
        ["Trip Name ", "Starting Time from Campus ", "Starting Spot & Time ", "Remarks"],
        ["Normal-1", "6:30 AM ", "Rupsha, 7:20 AM ", "Will back via Royalmore & Ferighat  "],
        ["Normal-1", "6:45 AM ", "Moylapota, 7:25 AM ", "Will back via Shibbari - Sonadangha "]
    ]
```

If you don't want to use headers of the table, just pretend like array's first element is not 0, it is 1.

If we talk about why you couldn't make it work; you are looking for `a` and `link` tags here `doc.xpath("//a | //link")`. But you have `td` tags. So you should do this: `doc.css("td")`. I used css function but I may use XPath too.

Good luck!

EDIT: You still should ask for an API. Preferably a RESTful JSON API.

EDIT 2: I used Swift 4 version of the Kanna. You may need to do some changes to use this with Swift 3.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please check it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Please uprate my question